# include video on website (non branded)

Tags: video, html5-video

I am wanting to include video on a website, however, the client would like the player to not have any branding and I am interested to know the best way to include video in the site, so it is cross browser ready?

I am aware of html 5, but it is only backwards compatible to ie9 and vimeo has a pro account but that has yearly charges. Any guidance would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I've already had the same case for a previous development.

The solution found : I've used [VideoJS Player](http://www.videojs.com) . If the current browser is not fully compatible with HTML5 (specially for play videos), so, link videojs.swf (Flash player instead).

Read the documentation on GitHub, it works perfectly for me.